# How do I convert my query to prepared statement?

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I have a working query that I want to convert to a prepared statement. So far, unfortunately without success. "affe4.jpg" should be exchanged to a variable $name:

```
    <?php

    $stmt = $con->query("UPDATE dbdateien
                            SET papierkorb=0
                            WHERE dateiname='affe4.jpg'");
    //$stmt->bindParam(':dateiname', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    //$stmt->execute();
    unset($stmt);

?>
```

I've updated my code, why isn't it working??

```html
            <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($erg AS $dateiname): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> <?php echo $dateiname['dateiname']; ?>
                                        <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="includes/wiederherstellen.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span> Wiederherstellen</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Endültig löschen</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><?php echo $dateien['dbuser.user'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                            <?php

                                var_dump($dateiname);

                                //$name = $_GET["name"];
                                $papierkorb=0;
                                $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE dbdateien
                                            SET papierkorb=:papierkorb
                                            WHERE dateiname=:dateiname");
                                $stmt->bindValue(':papierkorb', $papierkorb, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                                $stmt->bindParam(':dateiname', $dateiname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $stmt->execute();
                                unset($stmt);

                            ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Here's my solution:

```html
                        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($erg AS $dateiname): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> <?php echo $dateiname['dateiname']; ?>
                                        <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="includes/wiederherstellen.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span> Wiederherstellen</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Endültig löschen</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><?php echo $dateien['dbuser.user'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                            <?php

                                //$name = $_GET["name"];
                                $papierkorb=0;
                                $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE dbdateien
                                            SET papierkorb=:papierkorb
                                            WHERE dateiname=:dateiname");
                                $stmt->bindValue(':papierkorb', $papierkorb, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                                $stmt->bindParam(':dateiname', $dateiname['dateiname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $stmt->execute();
                                unset($stmt);

                            ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where's the according placeholder in the query? Why not use a positional `dateiname=?` and a list with `->execute([$v1])` after `->prepare`?

Comment: `affe4.jp` should be exchanged to `$name`. The placeholder should be `:dateiname`. Sorry, I don't understand your 2 question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming it's PDO:

```
$sth = $con->prepare("
    UPDATE dbdateien
       SET papierkorb=0
     WHERE dateiname=?
");
$sth->execute( [ $name ] );
```

Have a look at the examples at [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). There are 2 ways to bind parameters: you can name them (`:dateiname`) or not (`?`). For just 1 parameter, using the placeholder `?` is less verbose.

Comment: Thanks Kenney,

the point is, that I don't know the name of "affe4.jpg". That was just a test code. How would it look like if I would use a variable `$dateiname`?

Comment: You'd use `$dateiname` instead of `"affe4.jpg"` ;-) Updated using `$name` from your commented out line.

Comment: @Erich . . . You are missing the point.  `$sth` is the prepared statement.  When you execute it (which you can do multiple times), you pass the value you want to `execute()`.

Comment: Sorry @Kenney, it was my mistake ;)

Comment: OK I understand, but why is the database entry for `papierkorb`not updating to `0`?

I will update my question

Comment: Probably because `$name` doesn't many any value of `dbdateien.dateiname`. How are you initialising it?

Comment: Sorry @Kenney, the correct variable is `$dateiname`, `$name` is a leftover of another test I did, when I've tried to exclude the code to another php file.

Comment: Ok. Well, debugging time then: do an `echo "<code>$dateiname</code>";` to see if it's set properly, and also do a manual query "SELECT dateiname FROM dbdateien" and see if it's actually there..

Comment: IT WORKS :D:D:D

My failure was, that I've tried to address an array

I will update my question with the solution.

Comment: One interestin point is, that it works when `$papierkorb` is set to `0`but not the other way with `1`, when already changed to `0` in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$papierkorb = 0;
$dateiname = "affe4.jpg";
$statement =
    "
    UPDATE dbdateien 
    SET papierkorb = :papierkorb
    WHERE dateiname = :dateiname
    ";
$query = $con->prepare($statement);
$query->bindValue(':papierkorb', $papierkorb, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':dateiname', $dateiname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

/*
//another example
$statement =
    "
    UPDATE dbdateien 
    SET papierkorb = :papierkorb
    WHERE dateiname = :dateiname
    ";
$query = $con->prepare($statement);

//example, first insert.
$papierkorb = 0;
$dateiname = "affe4.jpg";
$query->execute(array(
    ':papierkorb'=>$papierkorb,
    ':dateiname'=>$dateiname
    ));

//second insert
$papierkorb = 1;
$dateiname = "affe5.jpg";
$query->execute(array(
    ':papierkorb'=>$papierkorb,
    ':dateiname'=>$dateiname
    ));
*/
?>
```